# Android: Interacting with the screen locks out the buttons

Tags: java, android, key

I have a both `onKeyDown` and `onMotionEvent` overriden in my application. Both of these work, but the `onKeyDown` has strange behavior. I can always interact with the screen on the device, but after I have interacted with the screen, the buttons do not work. In order to make them work again, I have to push other buttons (ones that I don't use) in order for them to work again. And if I interact with the screen again, the buttons will not work again.

The application I am writing is a game, so the button calls are made to the surface and then passed to the thread running the game.

I am debugging on an HTC Aria, but the problem persists in my emulators as well.

EDIT

The basic code I have is the same as is detailed [here](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html).

The code for the buttons are as follows:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
     return thread.doKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     return thread.doTouchEvent(event);
    }


    public boolean doKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
     synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
       showDialog(DIALOG_PAUSED_ID);
                            return true;
      }
      return false;
     }
    }

    public boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
      if (mState == STATE_PLAYING) {
       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
              if (event.getX() > 2 * (mWallX / 3)) {

               //shoot arrow
               shoot(event.getX(), event.getY());

               //turn player
               mPlayer.rotate(event.getX(), event.getY());

            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && event.getX() < 2 * (mWallX / 3)) {
         //temp button on left for stress test
               stressTest = !stressTest;
               return true;
        }
       }
      }
   return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: What do you return from onKeyDown?

Comment: Are you blocking the UI thread? I.e. passing control from event handler to game code. Can you post the offending code?

Comment: post code..you are probably blocking the UI thread which would describe the key behavior you are seeing/experiencing

Comment: Posted my button code. What exactly would I need to do to prevent it from blocking the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Logcat and watch the messages that appear when you recreate your problem.

If you see something like "key dispatching timeout" then the buttons are working, your code is simply busy, blocking any new input from being received.

Comment: If my code is busy, how would I go about making this work? Any help would be appreciated, I am stumped.

Comment: I can't say for sure without the code to your "shoot" and "rotate" methods, but it looks like you are running the game thread in the same thread as the UI thread.  This is a no-no.  Go research some of the google examples, such as LunarLander.

Comment: I had actually originally based my code off of the LunarLander example, and I had the exact same problem.